# How to I get id from a form to another js file from a loop (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
  $(data).each(function(index,worker){

  if (drupal_user.uid == worker.user && comp.nid == worker.company_id){ // user is logged in and has company assigned

            $( '.title' ).text( comp.node_title);
            $(".list-group").append(

            '<li class="list-group-item"><strong>Name: </strong><a href="worker.html" >' 
            + worker.node_title + 
            '</a><form><input type="hidden" id="nid" value="' + worker.nid + '"></form></li>'

          );
        }
        else { // user is not logged in or has no companies

        }

        });
```

It creates a loop of many workers and takes data from ajax request. Now I need to show just one worker info if you click on a worker name. It seems like an easy thing to do but Iv been stuck for some time now.

Answer (score 0):

You create the function outside the loop. All the `<li>` tags will then use that function. Normally for better practice you could put that function inside a namespace.

```
var severalFunctions = {
    getWorkerInfo: function(worker) {
        $('tagToPlaceData').text(worker) // Use worker object correct, depending on what it contains
    }
}
/* Your code under here */
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But how can i add the function inside the loop?

Comment: You create the function outside the loop. All the `<li>` tags will then use that function. Normally for better practice you could put that function inside a namespace.  See my updated answer